# How to run Appium python tests in parallel on devicefarm

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, appium, aws-device-farm, python-appium

Is is possible to run my appium python tests in parallel on aws devicefarm, i know we can select multiple devices from the aws device pool but that runs the same time on all selected devices,
i wanted to distribute my tests on multiple devices,

Comment: you need to start more than one appium server and tell your devices to use them

Comment: how can i tell devicefarm devices to you my appium server?

Comment: that depends on the appium server port , for example ` appium -U "Device id" -p 4733`

Comment: but i'm asking about devicefarm how can i find deviceid of devicefarm device and also devicefarm run its own appium server